# Why I don't see all my post in feed in Wordpress

Tags: feed

I have a question. I want to get all my post but when I visit http://example.com/feed/atom/ I have only three post. In my website there are much more than three. How to update this file?

Kind regards

Comment: I can see many solutions and discussions on this same topic with a simple Google. Like [this one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/latest-post-not-showing-on-rss-feed/) or [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4736/22728). What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your settings option, by going to **Settings > Reading** and check for number of items in **Syndication feeds show the most recent**. I have attached a screenshot of the option too.

This should fix the issue I guess. Do let us know.

[image: Number of posts in feed]

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, actually. Have you got a custom written template, or you use a pre-programmed one? If you use a ready-made template, I assume that the problem lies in the settings. Then @made2popupar's answer should solve it. If not, I'm afraid, that we have not enough information to help. You should post how does your post searching loop looks like.